# Drag and drop without removing UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing a drag and drop system in an iphone app. So far I managed to implement the draggable button and it is working fine. This is the code that I have:

First, I assign the action to the button:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

then, I create the drag:

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    NSLog(@"moved");
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIControl *control = sender;
    control.center = point;
}
```

However, what I want to achieve is that the button being dragged doesn't gets removed from where it is. So I thought of one solution that is to create a new button similar to the first and move the this newly created button. But I having trouble in implementing this last part. 
Any help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {
    NSLog(@"moved");          

    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    if (![self.view viewWithTag:11]) {

        NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:(UIButton*)sender];                

        UIButton *anotherButton =(UIButton*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];

        anotherButton.tag = 11;    


        UIImage *senderImage=[(UIButton *)sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];




        CGImageRef cgImage = [senderImage CGImage];


        UIImage *copyOfImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];



        [anotherButton setImage:copyOfImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.view addSubview:anotherButton];
    }

    [self.view viewWithTag:11].center = point;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. It seems to be right what I need but somehow it is throwing the exception: `-[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6323500` when it reaches the line: `NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sender];`. Can you see what is throwing the exception?

Comment: u asked to move UIButton but u have used it to uiimageview

Comment: again i changed the code above just copy and paste again and reply

Comment: still throws the same exception. Could it be because I'm using UIButtonTypeCustom? `self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Comment: for testing purpose remove image from button and give some name to button and run and reply

Comment: Ok, so I did that and it doesn't throw the exception anymore. And it is creating the copy of the button. But the behavior is not great. It breaks and have unexpected behavior.

Comment: It's the same. Looks like it is restricted to move only within a stripe about 100 pixels up and down.

Comment: It's still restricted. The behavior is all fine. Just this bounds restriction is strange because if I don't do the copy of the view it can be dragged outside this bounds

Answer (score 0):

To remove the restriction you can add two events on the origin button like so:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
```

This way the event will fire too when you exit the bounds of the current view (your button) and you'll be able to move the new button all arround the superview.